# Is there any equivalent for GitLab CI/CD's environment file in GCP cloud build?

Tags: gitlab, google-cloud-build, cicd

I'm using GitLab's CI/CD for building and deploying my application. As my deployment environment is GCP, I'm trying to use GCP cloud build to build and deploy my application to the cloud. In GitLab, I was using it's environment file feature to store certain critical files. Is there any alternative for that in GCP's cloud build?

I'm storing some configuration files and some other files as environment file. How can I completely replace GitLab CI/CD with GCP Cloud build?

Comment: Does [this](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact use Cloud Build for CI/CD and GitHub for *Source Code Management* as you usually do using GitLab, in that way you can build and deploy your apps on GCP and still be able to manage your source code.
In this guide of [Similarities and differences between GitLab CI and Cloud Build](https://medium.com/stash-media/similarities-and-differences-between-gitlab-ci-and-cloud-build-aa1e1f9eae0e), there is an explanation on how to build and deploy your code with Cloud Build. The steps in a few words would be:

1. Connect Cloud Build to your source repository
2. Select the repository where your source code is with authentication
3. Add a trigger to automate the builds using a Dockerfile or Cloud Build config file in YAML format

Also, a brief explanation of some important fields:

> - The `steps` field in the config file specifies a set of steps that you want Cloud Build to perform.
> - The `id` field sets a unique identifier for a build step.
> - The `name` field of a build step specifies a cloud builder, which is a container image running common tools. You use a builder in a build step to execute your tasks.
> - The `args` field of a build step takes a list of arguments and passes them to the builder referenced by the name field.
> - The `entrypoint` in a build step specifies an entrypoint if you don't want to use the default entrypoint of the builder.

To store config files, you can refer to [Storing images in Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers#store-images):

> You can configure Cloud Build to store your built image in one of the following ways:
>
> - using the images field, which stores the image in the Container Registry after your build completes.
> - using the docker push command, which stores the image in the Container Registry as part of your build flow.

If your build produces artifacts like binaries or tarballs, as mentioned in  [Storing build artifacts](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/store-build-artifacts), you can store them in Cloud Storage.

In case you want to use variables, I would refer to the [site](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) mentioned in a previous comment.